# Grails validate a password

Tags: grails

In a controller how can i validate a password so it contains at least 1 letter, 1 number, 1 special character and is at least 8 digits long. The code i am trying to use is as follows:

```
  boolean validatePassword(String password) {
    System.out.println("In validate")
   def pattern = /^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%*&+()]).*$/
    def matcher = password =~ pattern
    System.out.println("HERERERE")
    return matcher.getCount() ? true : false
}
```

This does not work if says everything is invalid.
I have spring security ui plug in installed. Is there a way I can use its validation features?
I know i can use it to encode the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to do everything in one regex I'd split up the tests.  Since in Groovy a `Matcher` coerces to boolean by calling `find()`, the following should work, and makes the intent clearer.

```
boolean validatePassword(String pass) {
  return (pass) && (pass.length() > 7) && (pass =~ /\p{Alpha}/) &&
         (pass =~ /\p{Digit}/) && (pass =~ /[!@#$%*&+()]/)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nice java library called vtpassword for this purpose if you need something more sophisticated

http://code.google.com/p/vt-middleware/wiki/vtpassword